# Render Text using SDL2 TTF and glDrawPixels

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I am currently adding support for a SDL2 windowing system to a library, that currently uses GLUT. This includes rendering text. The problematic part is that I don't have access to the `Window` or `Renderer` at the position where text rendering happens. Previously text was rendered with GLUT using the `glutBitmapCharacter` function.

I am very close to solving this, by using `glDrawPixels`, but the output looks like this:
[image: Output]

It seems, that the texture is flipped and some noise is rendered above. I tried playing with the `GL_UNPACK_XXX` functions, but couldn't find out how to fix that. Do you have some idea?

Here is a sample application, that reproduces this issuse:

`main.cpp:`

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

const int width = 400;
const int height = 400;

TTF_Font* font = nullptr;

// THIS FUNCTION IS THE ONLY THING I CAN CHANGE!
void drawText(std::string text) {
  SDL_Color color = {
    static_cast<Uint8>(255),
    static_cast<Uint8>(0),
    static_cast<Uint8>(255),
    static_cast<Uint8>(255)
  };

  SDL_Surface* textRender = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, text.c_str(), color);
  SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(textRender, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 0);
  SDL_FreeSurface(textRender);

  glPushAttrib(GL_BLEND);
  glPushAttrib(GL_BLEND_EQUATION);
  glPushAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES,  GL_FALSE);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_LSB_FIRST,   GL_FALSE);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH,  surface->pitch);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS,   0);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,   1);

  glDrawPixels(surface->w, surface->h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

  glPopAttrib();
  glPopAttrib();
  glPopAttrib();

  SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}

// EVERYTHING BELOW HERE IS ONLY TO PROVIDE A MINIMUM REPRODUCABLE EXAMPLE!

void loop(int64_t frame) {
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glRasterPos2f(-1.0, 0);
  drawText(std::string("Hello World!") + std::to_string(frame));
}

int main() {
  SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  TTF_Init();

  auto* window = SDL_CreateWindow("sdl-text", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
  auto* context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
  glewInit();

  bool quit = false;
  int64_t frame = 0;

  font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 42);
  if (!font) {
    quit = true;
  }

  while (!quit) {
    loop(frame++);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
      switch(e.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
          quit = true;
          break;
      }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(16));
  }

  TTF_Quit();
  SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  return 0;
}
```

compiled with the following command:

```bash
g++ main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lGLEW -lGL
```

Comment: Just a random guess, but have you tried  ``glRasterPos2f(-1,1)`` and ``glPixelZoom( 1, -1 )``? Also ``glDrawPixels`` is a relic of legacy OpenGL; could you use the modern OpenGL pipeline to render a quad, convert ``surface`` to a texture, use ``glTexImage2D``, and render the quad with the texture? Or are you limited to legacy?

Comment: If you don't have the capability to create a quad using modern OpenGL, you could create one with the legacy pipeline (it supports OpenGL textures)

Comment: I can use modern OpenGL, but sadly I don't have access to the coordinates, as they are set in the calling code of the function. Do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Oh! That is the raster position. Then use ``glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos)`` to query the raster position. BTW, `glDrawPixels` uses the raster position, thus why it is able to get the coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems like OpenGL takes the row length in pixel and SDL provides it in bytes. This is easily solved.

We also don't need to convert the surface to RGBA. We can just tell OpenGL to draw BGRA (although SDL says it provides AGBR, but it works).

Finally we flip the image before drawing with `glPixelZoom(1, -1)`.
To offset the flip we have to move it up by the height.

The solution is the following:

```cpp
void drawText(std::string text) {
  SDL_Color color = {
    static_cast<Uint8>(255),
    static_cast<Uint8>(0),
    static_cast<Uint8>(0),
  };

  // We dont't need to convert the surface format.
  SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, text.c_str(), color);

  glPushAttrib(GL_BLEND);
  glPushAttrib(GL_BLEND_EQUATION);
  glPushAttrib(GL_CLIENT_PIXEL_STORE_BIT);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

  // SDL uses bytes, while OpenGL uses pixels.
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, surface->pitch / surface->format->BytesPerPixel);

  // Get the current raster position.
  std::array<float, 4> pos;
  glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, pos.data());

  // Because the texture is upside down we move it up by the height and flip it.
  glWindowPos2f(pos[0], pos[1] + surface->h);
  glPixelZoom(1, -1);

  // Use BGRA as a format.
  glDrawPixels(surface->w, surface->h, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

  glPopAttrib();
  glPopAttrib();
  glPopAttrib();

  SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```